# Install extension using composer in yii2.0

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions

How can i install yii/jui in yii2.0 using composer. I have tried

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui "*"
```

and added to **composer.json**

```
"yiisoft/yii2-jui": "*"
```

but it did not succeed. Can anyone help me how to use composer to install extension in  yii 2.0 .

When i am running `$ php composer.phar require yiisoft/yii2-jui "*"` in cmd it is just opening the composer.phar file, nothing else happening.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please check in composer.json file for yiisoft/yii2-jui under "require". You might be see like that

```
"require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "2.0.*@dev"
},
```

If you didn't see, please add this and run **composer.phar install** or **composer install**. If already install, use **composer.phar update** or **composer update**

I have been updated my answer. Please take a look. The packagist is [Here](https://packagist.org/packages/yiisoft/yii2-jui).

Comment: Hello kelvin i am not able to create yiisoft/yii2-jui folder. So help me first to create yii2-jui folder inside yiisoft

Comment: No need to create folder that using composer.

Comment: So how i will get yiisoft/yii2-jui folder. By using php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui "*" just opening composer.phar file . Plz help me .

Comment: i am talking about https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui plz look in the installation section i am using php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui "*" to install yii2-jui but it isopening just composer.phar file. so help me to install yiisoft/yii2-jui through composer.

Comment: for me composer. phar update or composer.update didn't work. I used php composer.phar update

Comment: @Bloodhound  Where your `composer.phar` location? Type this command `which composer`

Answer (score 9):

Hopefully, you already installed Yii-2 with composer. I have been installed (basic application template) step by step.

Step 1. 
    Before installation, Yii official website said that, we require to install this package before installation Yii 2. This step will follow after composer installation.

```
sudo composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"
```

Please take a look attach file.

[image]

This time is yii-2 installation with composer.

```
sudo composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.1
```

Please take a second and third attach image.

[image]

[image]

After that, please go to your project folder. Then, open ***your_project_folder/composer.json***. I have been used **vi** to open **compser.json**. You can use whatever your prefer. Please take a look again for attach image.

[image]

The next step is final step for complete install for your package. After adding this

```
"yiisoft/yii2-jui": "*"
```

under **require** keyword, please save your **composer.json** file. Then run this command.

```
 sudo composer update
```

Please take a look attach image again.

[image]

Please check your folder on ***your_project_folder/vender/yiisoft/yii2-jui***

[image]

That's all. Hope this help for your stack. Btw, if you want to use **composer** command, please used the following command. This will help to call **composer** from everywhere.

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows 10,  To install php `composer.phar` requires `--prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui`.